# Long task after await in an async method

Tags: c#, json.net, async-await

While the following question is generally applicable to all usage of async/await in C#, it refers to Json.NET. The `JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync()` method has been marked as obsolete by the development team as it would be difficult to maintain and not of much use since most JSON files are small (Refer [this](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/66)).

I have some code following this structure:

```
public async Task<CarObj> GetCarAsync()
{
    string json = await GetJsonStringFromRestEndpoint();
    // At this point, we should already be on a separate thread since we have awaited a long running task.

    // 1 - Running this relatively long task on this thread should be fine since we're already on a new thread than the caller.
    CarObj obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarObj>(json);

    // 2 - Would this better for some reason?
    CarObj obj2 = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarObj>(json));
}
```

Would option 1 or 2 in the code above be the better solution here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arguably this is primarily opinion-based. But…

Assuming the library authors are correct, your first option is better. But not for the reason you think.

When the `await GetJsonStringFromRestEndpoint()` completes, then assuming the `GetCarAsync()` method was called from a thread with a synchronization context, the call to `DeserializeObject<CarObj>(json);` will happen on that same thread.

The reason calling the method synchronously isn't a problem isn't because you're on a different thread (you're not), but rather because as the library authors point out, the input data isn't likely to be large enough for there to be any significant performance problem. You can probably parse the entire JSON data and construct your `CarObj` value in less time than it takes to queue up the thread pool work item, context-switch to that thread, and then context-switch back.

In other words, don't use worker threads to perform computationally inexpensive work.

Comment: In this specific case, the json is a fairly large one and takes around 50ms on average to desrialize. Is running it on a separate thread still not justified?

Comment: _"Is running it on a separate thread still not justified?"_ -- what is the context? can anything else useful happen in your program while the deserialization is occurring? 50ms is long enough that you might get some concurrency by using `Task.Run()` around the call, but that only helps if there's a good reason to yield the current thread. And if all you're dealing with is a UI, the user is unlikely to notice a 50ms delay. There's not really enough info in your question to know for sure what's best. But the number of scenarios where pushing a 50ms task to a worker thread is useful, are limited.

Comment: My use case is an api library. Would I be smarter pushing concurrency here since the application is unknown?

Comment: What if I had called `.ConfigureAwait(false)`? Now the processing would be on a separate thread. How would this change your answer?

Comment: _"Would I be smarter pushing concurrency here"_ -- that depends on what your library is advertising. I would only add concurrency if that's actually the _primary_ design goal of the library. Otherwise, let the caller decide whether to introduce that or not. They can always wrap your method in task if they need to. They can't _remove_ the concurrency if it's adding overhead they don't.

Comment: _"What if I had called .ConfigureAwait(false)?"_ -- then the answer changes only insofar as the observed behavior of `await`, not the more general issues at hand. That is, yes...doing that causes the continuation to _not_ be put back on the original thread. But that's not really the issue here. The bigger issue is a) the minimal or non-existent benefit of using a worker thread to deserialize, and b) whether client code is going to expect the deserialization to occur concurrently with anything else. Again, I don't have enough details to know in your case what's best.

Comment: But, sorry, "*doing that causes the continuation to not be put back on the original thread*" and following point a) are related one with the other: the original thread is the one that could possibly benefit from the continuation  (i.e. deserialize) not yielding back

Comment: @user1892538: there is a philosophy that states that, in library code, awaited async calls should include `ConfigureAwait(false)`, so that continuations aren't marshalled back to the calling thread unless necessary (and the caller has control over that if they need it). But that's not really the crux of the question here...this question has to do with whether to wrap the **non**-asynchronous element of the method in a `Task.Run()`, making it also asynchronous and concurrent. This is orthogonal to the question of whether or not `ConfigureAwait(false)` should be used.

Comment: If the continuation `DeserializeObject` is *not marshalled back to the* UI thread, this is similar to wrap the **same** `DeserializeObject` in a Task.Run()

Comment: _"They can always wrap your method in task if they need to. They can't remove the concurrency if it's adding overhead they don't."_ That's a really good point you make. However, I think I wasn't clear with my second question earlier. Consider a case where there was actually a correct `DeserializeObjectAsync` method, and I had used `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Now we would be on a different thread than the caller and have only one last async function left. Would using a non async variant of it make a difference? (i.e is calling an async function at the end better than a non-async one?)

Comment: _" there was actually a correct `DeserializeObjectAsync` method, and I had used `ConfigureAwait(false)`"_ -- sorry, don't understand what you're asking. It would only make sense to call `ConfigureAwait()` on the first call (`GetJsonStringFromRestEndpoint()`). Adding that to the last statement in the method doesn't do anything useful. If you add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the `GetJsonStringFromRestEndpoint()` call, then I see no point in using `DeserializeObjectAsync()`. It's not clear to me where you are saying you'd add `ConfigureAwait()`, but regardless, I wouldn't use the deprecated method

Answer (score 0):

> // At this point, we should already be on a separate thread since we have awaited a long running task.

No, the *caller thread* is called back (resumed) instead.

But - if this is *not* your intended behavior - I'd advice to add

```
 .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

That would save some synchronization work and afterwards you'll reasonably expect to be in a thread pull thread.